# EXCEL VBA Transpose multiple columns to multiple rows with gaps inbetween columns

Tags: excel, vba, transpose, unpivot

I have a large dataset to transpose and the code below does exactly that in the correct output however with a few too many columns. Currently the code will continuously read from column to column until it has them all. I would like to change this so I can select the first columns data, skip 3 columns then continue the script.

```
My Dataset:
UFI   CAT1    CAT2    CAT3    CAT4   CAT5   CAT6
RN1   Skip1   Skip2   Skip3   Copy1  Copy2  Copy3
RN2   Skip1   Skip2   Skip3   Copy1  Copy2  Copy3

Desired Output:
UFI    COLUMN   VALUES
RN1    CAT5     Copy1
RN1    CAT6     Copy2
RN1    CAT7     Copy3
RN2    CAT5     Copy1
RN2    CAT6     Copy2
RN2    CAT7     Copy3
```

Here is the VBA code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

Dim p

'get the unpivoted data as a 2-D array
p = UnPivotData(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                3, True, False)

Dim r As Long, c As Long
For r = 1 To UBound(p, 1)

    For c = 1 To UBound(p, 2)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, c).Value = p(r, c)
    Next c

Next r

End Sub

Function UnPivotData(rngSrc As Range, fixedCols As Long, _
                 Optional AddCategoryColumn As Boolean = True, _
                 Optional IncludeBlanks As Boolean = True)

Dim nR As Long, nC As Long, data, dOut()
Dim r As Long, c As Long, rOut As Long, cOut As Long, cat As Long
Dim outRows As Long, outCols As Long

data = rngSrc.Value                          'get the whole table as a 2-D 
array
nR = UBound(data, 1)                         'how many rows
nC = UBound(data, 2)                         'how many cols

'calculate the size of the final unpivoted table
outRows = nR * (nC - fixedCols)
outCols = fixedCols + IIf(AddCategoryColumn, 2, 1)

'resize the output array
ReDim dOut(1 To outRows, 1 To outCols)

'populate the header row
For c = 1 To fixedCols
    dOut(1, c) = data(1, c)
Next c
If AddCategoryColumn Then
    dOut(1, fixedCols + 1) = "COLUMN"
    dOut(1, fixedCols + 2) = "VALUES"
Else
    dOut(1, fixedCols + 1) = "VALUES"
End If


'populate the data
rOut = 1
For r = 2 To nR
    For cat = fixedCols + 1 To nC


        If IncludeBlanks Or Len(data(r, cat)) > 0 Then
            rOut = rOut + 1
            'Fixed columns...
            For c = 1 To fixedCols
                dOut(rOut, c) = data(r, c)
            Next c
            'populate unpivoted values
            If AddCategoryColumn Then
                dOut(rOut, fixedCols + 1) = data(1, cat)
                dOut(rOut, fixedCols + 2) = data(r, cat)
            Else
                dOut(rOut, fixedCols + 1) = data(r, cat)
            End If
        End If

    Next cat
Next r

UnPivotData = dOut
End Function
```

Comment: The dataset is actually about 15 columns long and expands to 500+ rows. Any guidance on how I can edit the range to include my changes is greatly appreciated

Comment: A quick workaround would be to copy the data to another sheet, delete the unwanted columns, then use the code as-is on the copy

Comment: Too focused on the code had me mind blanking, just realised that right as you were posting :) thank you kindly for the guidance towards that code. definitely helped alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of it:

```
Sub Skip_and_Transpose()

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet: Set Ws1 = Sheets(1)
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet: Set Ws2 = Sheets(2)
Dim P1 As Range: Set P1 = Ws1.UsedRange
T1 = P1
Dim T2()
a = 1

ReDim Preserve T2(1 To 3, 1 To a)
T2(1, a) = "UFI"
T2(2, a) = "COLUMN"
T2(3, a) = "VALUES"
a = a + 1

For i = 2 To UBound(T1)
    For j = 5 To UBound(T1, 2)
        ReDim Preserve T2(1 To 3, 1 To a)
        T2(1, a) = T1(i, 1)
        T2(2, a) = T1(1, j)
        T2(3, a) = T1(i, j)
        a = a + 1
    Next j
Next i

Ws2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(T2, 2), UBound(T2)) = Application.Transpose(T2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this method is proving much faster. Could you please show how to edit the amount of columns skipped? for example if I want it to collect the 1st column, skip the next 10 columns and then continue from the 11th column?

Comment: scratch that, just found it. "For j = 5 to Ubound"

Comment: Yes, starting from index 5 skips the first 4 columns. If you want to skip in between columns, you can add an `IF/END IF` condition in the loop like `If j < 2 or j > 4 then` ... just after the `For j = 1 to Ubound(T1,2)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tims assistance, I was able to reach a work around.

In order to do this, im going to add a new hidden sheet that the VBA code will target instead, the hidden sheet will have my dataset with all the skipped columns removed to allow the VBA to read normally from the hidden sheet while operating all this from my working sheet.

The desired output will be the same without the need of editting the VBA code to make exceptions for columns